# Tableau Boolean Column of "Yes","No" Ater Using If Function to Numbers But I Am Getting Zero

Tags: tableau-desktop

Tableau Boolean Column  of "Yes","No" After Using If Function **IF Churn Label = "Yes" Then 1 Else 0 End** to Get Number Say **1,345** But I Am Getting Zero **0**

Comment: Please share your workbook in tableau public, you can find examples here : https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/debayan.kar

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, what you think is "Yes" probably isn't. If you've set an alias on a field that is, for example "Y" or "N", your calculated fields have to refer to the "Y", not the alias. Presumably your Y/N column is already a string (not a Boolean) because you're not getting a type error for the query of [Churn Labe] = "Yes".